# RigidBody gravityScale not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a `rigidBody`, it attached to game object like this:

```
obj = GameObject.Find ("spider");
body = obj.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
body.angularVelocity = 180f;
```

So it's moving by gravity influence down from the screen, but i want it to stop at some point, so i've made a condition :

```
if (obj.transform.position.y < 0) {
    Debug.Log("Stop point");
    body.gravityScale = 0.0f;
}
```

I see in logs message "Stop Point" which notifies me that gravity should be stopped, but nothing is happening and object still going down, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GravityScale indicate how many the gravity affect to your object. If your object is in movement, its have velocity, and gravity to 0 only tell that not add force to your gameobject, not stop this. Think that with gravity 0 is similar to an object in outspace, but with velocity its never stop.
Use Addforce or Set velocity to stop your object.

```
body.velocity = Vector2.zero;
body.angularVelocity = 0.0f;

//Ensure not move
body.Sleep()
```

Comment: Yes, this resolved my problem : body.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
   body.angularVelocity = 0f; thank you And also: i'll be asking some basic unity questions, so you can help me and get easy reputation))

Comment: you can ensure that not move a mm adding a last line of code with body.Sleep(); i edit my post adding this

Comment: angularVelocity is a float, not Vector, and this is 2D object, so velocity is Vector2, but i understood you, thanks

Comment: @NikMyers do you like a chat for the basic questions or you go to publish new posts?

Comment: i have no questions for the moment, they are appearing as my project goes further)